# Supremum norm of certain quantity II

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, cv.complex-variables, euclidean-geometry

Can anyone solve the maximization problem...$\max_{|z_i|=1}\Big|\sum_{i,j=1}^nz_iz_j+\sum_{i,j=1}^n|z_i-z_j|\Big|$?

Comment: is the first summand just $(\sum z_i)^2$?